# How to debug Android app on Samsung Smart TV

Tags: android, samsung-smart-tv

I'm a student programmer creating an Android application for Smart TV (Samsung) use. I would like to debug my project on the Smart TV just like how I can enter debug mode on my android phone. I tried searching but to no avail. Can anyone guide me through this? Thank you.

Comment: Good question. Also include Smart TV specifications(s/w).

Comment: Is there a way of connecting to your computer? What does the Smart TV manual say? What does the Samsung website say?

Comment: @andy256 Manual only described how to connect to a computer via HDMI cable but there's a USB port located at the back of the TV as well.

Comment: I don't get your question.
- Is your android apps is "nservice" apps which you want to debug?
- Is your android apps is a debugger for Samsung TV Apps?
- Is your Samsung TV Apps is a debugger for the android apps?

Answer (score 1):

I notice that there is a [Smart TV developers forum](http://developer.samsung.com/smarttv).

They also provide a link to download their SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JS Debugger tool provided with the Samsung SDK:

- [Debugging and Testing Applications](http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_2/getting_started/debugging_test_app.html)
- [JS Debugger](http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_2/sdktools/js_debugger_intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ist of all You can't run andriod app on Samsung Smart Tv as Samsung Smart Tv dont Support android app.

You can build app for samsung smart tv using Samsung SDK's which largely use HTML5,CSS,JavaScript, Jquery.

You can find rest information on [Samsung Developer forum](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/)